# ViewPagerIndicator causing app to crash

Tags: android, android-library, viewpagerindicator

when I import the viewpagerindicator project library into my application that works without the support library, it crashes on launch.  I've tried it with more than one application with the same results.  Here is the logcat output:

```
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589): Process: com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample, PID: 589
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample-9.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample-9, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample-9.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample-9, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2222)
06-14 17:19:02.351: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: is the activity declared in the manifest?

Comment: At the moment there is only one activity and it is declared.  The app worked before the inclusion of the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the problem was that all of my android-support-v4.jar library files were different.  So all I did was copied the latest v4 .jar files into the "libs" folder of both my project and library, added it to the build path, and voilà no more crashes!